# Can we maintain/track Cosmos DB DDL script changes in a Git repository like what we do in Azure SQL?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

When I work Azure SQL data tables, I can maintain/track changes to DDL script files in a git repository.

Do we have a similar approach for Cosmos DB?

Can we script a Cosmos Database and its Containers in a file and source control change track them in a Git repository?

What is the recommended directory structure for Cosmos DB DDL scripts?

This is not a CI/CD question and Yes we can store executable scripts in source control.

My question is if we can script a CosmosDB into a file (probably json) similar to what we can do in SQL Server Management studio.

Is that possible?

Comment: This really is a very broad, discussion-style question, and not a programming question. I would suggest looking at the various powershell and cli commands for Cosmos DB, which allow for Cosmos DB management, as well as the related SDKs. tl;dr yes, you can store all of your CI/CD code (including cli/powershell use) in version control. How you approach this is really up to you.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, thank you for help. Please see my comment and check if the question makes sense now. To me, Cosmos DB is very much developer centric products (like other No SQL projects) and the focus of this question is if the product provides what the feature that I am looking. This should be a fair straight forward question for an experienced cosmos developer. I am new to Cosmos.

Comment: Cosmos does not use DDL like SQL. Cosmos is native to Azure. You use ARM, Bicep, Terraform, PS, CLI or Azure Management SDK, etc. (and to a lesser extent, Cosmos DB's SDKs) to manage Cosmos DB resources. These of course provide IaC that you can store in Git.

Comment: Yes, we use ARM based approach to provision any Azure services. However, once we provision a service we then deploy workload to it using a relevant technology - usually other than ARM based. For example, once we provision an Azure SQL using ARM based tools (like Bicep) we use different tooling to  deploy a workload to it.

Comment: Ok, well if you're going to use ARM/Bicep to deploy and maintain your Cosmos resources, you kind of need to continue using them. Otherwise you will get unexpected results when properties that were subsequently changed are set back to their original values. Unless of course you update the templates with those later values.

Comment: I would suggest checking out the Cosmos DB docs for further info, at this point. The SQL-based language has no provision for creating things like databases, collections, or documents, so there's no equivalent "scripting of database assets" as found in relational databases. Both Mark and I have pointed out that you can manage infrastructure code in git, and you can use git to manage SDK-based code that creates/updates your databases/collections.

Comment: @MarkBrown, please note that ARM (and its favors) are suited when we deploy an Azure Service. However, ARM is not meant to deploy Cosmos artifacts such as containers, indexes etc.

Comment: @AllanXu, that's not correct. ARM templates and everything else I mentioned is designed to be (and is) used to deploy and manage every type of Cosmos DB resource from the database account and including containers, indexes and anything else that is defined in our resource provider.

Comment: @MarkBrown, thank you for engaging in this conversation. To my limited knowledge, using ARM to deploy schema object in SQL Azure is not a common practice. Do you know if ARM is the recommended way for deploying schema objects (like indexes) in Cosmos DB? I can use C# code to do the same, but I was thinking to build on top of the productive schema deployment patterns we have for SQL Azure.

Comment: For Cosmos DB, yes, you use ARM to manage all things in Cosmos DB. There is no DDL as you find with SQL DB.

Comment: @AllanXu please avoid extended discussion - this isn't what comments are for. Maybe move this to [chat]?